# How to do this c++ looping

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I am sorry i'm new learner in programming. I would like to ask for help where i want to display a range number start from 200 until 400 but it should not display number 250 in it.

This is what i have done.

```
int main () {
     for (int i=200; i<=400; i++) {
         std::cout << "value of i: " << i << endl;  
     }

     return 0;
 }
```

I was sucessfuly display the range number, but it display all number.

Comment: Where exactly do you _try_ not to display 250?

Comment: `if (i != 250)`?

Comment: @Chad maybe a little complicated to just omit 250

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 250 is the only number you don't want to display in your range, you need to use and `if` statement. This statement would be stating that you should print number only if they are different from 250.

```
 for (int i=200; i<=400; i++) {
     if (i != 250) { // if my current number i is different from 250 I print it
         std::cout << "value of i: " << i << std::endl;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to avoid the `if` for every iteration, you could of course also split it into two loops:

```
for (int i = 200; i < 250; ++i)
  std::cout << "value of i: " << i << endl;
for (int i = 251; i <= 400; ++i)
  std::cout << "value of i: " << i << endl;
```

Pretty simple, but simple can be very good in this business.

Comment: +1 for a non branching answer. Not going to be costly in this scenario but OP will live a happy life if they set their sights on optimising speed this early on :-)